# Plural of yasher koach?

Tags: blessing, hebrew, language

Many expressions in Hebrew take different forms when referring to women or groups. What is the correct way to say yasher koach/ײשר כּח to multiple people?

Comment: Is this question about Judaism?

Comment: Just tack on the appropriate plurals? יישרו כחכם/כן?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yashar kochachem יישר כחכם (the koach - strength - is in the plural form)

Comment: Can you [edit] support for this claim? WADR, none of us know who you are to accept it on your say-so. Is this perhaps grammatically correct (and how do you know) or very common (and in what circles) or something you heard an authority say (and who)?

Comment: @Miriam Thanks! But is this definitely for multiple people, or merely to acknowledge multiple "strengths"?

Comment: I'm not sure .. usually, the verb must match the object in number. Shouldn't it be yeyashru kokhachem. The way you have it implies that one person has multiple strengths. This is true, but, in this case, I don't think that's what you meant. Of course, for females, it would be "Teyasheru kochachen". I've never heard this, but seems sensible to me.

Comment: The koach (strength) stays in the singular - your (pl.) strength. I don't have a grammatical explanation, but this is what is used. I googled for some different examples: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_47276_150.pdf (top line), http://www.kosharot.co.il/order.asp?id=42227 (one letter from last from the bottom of the page), https://www.headstart.co.il/projectcomments.aspx?id=7257 (3rd comment down).